# Going through columns in an array and copying the data

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a code that goes through multiples files (>100). It opens the file, and puts that information to an array. At each new file, the number of items in the rows may change (increase or decrease). I use a second array to account for that.

The column headers change in the files too (headers in different column positions). My problem is that I am trying to go through the columns on the first row (header), see if they are in that file array, and if they are, copy that info to the output file (if they are not, place an "--").

Current code is:

```
Sub Price()
Dim w As Workbook
Dim w2 As Workbook
Dim start1 As Long, end1 As Long, i As Long, lRow As Long, lColumn As Long, t As Long, k As Long, position As Long, g As Long, p As Long, u As Long
Dim WBArray() As Variant
Dim r As Range
Dim Header(): ReDim Header(0)
Dim IS3(): ReDim IS3(0) 'this fix the subscript out of range error
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String

Set w = ThisWorkbook

'clean all worksheets in the main file (except FILES)
For Each ws In w.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "FILES" Then
        ws.UsedRange.ClearContents
    End If
Next ws

'Optimize Macro Speed Start
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'opens the first workbook file
For i = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FILES").Cells(1, 2).Value

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.path & "\" &     ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FILES").Cells(i, 1).Value

    Set w2 = ActiveWorkbook
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Select

    'text to columns
    Selection.TextToColumns destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=True, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7 _
        , 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array(16, 1), Array(17 _
        , 1), Array(18, 1), Array(19, 1), Array(20, 1), Array(21, 1), Array(22, 1), Array(23, 1), Array(24, 1), Array(25, 1), Array(26, 1), Array(27 _
        , 1), Array(28, 1), Array(29, 1), Array(30, 1), Array(31, 1), Array(32, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True




'create the array based on whanted data
With ActiveSheet
Set r = .Columns(1).Find(what:="ISIN", After:=.Cells(.Rows.count, 1), lookat:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
If Not r Is Nothing Then
    start1 = r.Row
    end1 = .Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    WBArray = .Range(Cells(start1, 1), Cells(end1, 29)).Value
End If
End With


'loop to match information in two arrays


     'option 1 ***************************************

            For lColumn = 2 To UBound(WBArray)
                If IsInArray((WBArray(1, lColumn)), Header) <> -1 Then
                    p = IsInArray((WBArray(1, lColumn)), Header)
                    'p is position when already in array

                Else
                    ReDim Preserve Header(LBound(Header) To UBound(Header) + 1)
                    Header(UBound(Header)) = WBArray(1, lColumn)

                    u = UBound(Header)
                    'u is position when not in array, redim to end
                End If
           Next lColumn



                For lRow = 2 To UBound(WBArray)
                      For lColumn = 2 To UBound(WBArray)
                        If IsInArray((WBArray(lRow, 1)), IS3) <> -1 Then
                            t = IsInArray((WBArray(lRow, 1)), IS3)



            If lColumn.Name = "Cpn" Then
                w.Sheets("Cpn").Cells(t, i + 3).Value = WBArray(lRow, lColumn)
            Else
                'w.Sheets("Cpn").Cells(t, i + 3).Value = "--"
                Resume Next
            End if    

            w.Sheets("M").Cells(t, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, lColumn)
            w.Sheets("W t-1").Cells(t, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, lColumn)
            w.Sheets("P").Cells(t, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, lColumn)
            w.Sheets("A").Cells(t, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, lColumn)
            w.Sheets("PC").Cells(t, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, lColumn)
            w.Sheets("AM").Cells(t, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, lColumn)
            w.Sheets("AM t-1").Cells(t, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, lColumn)
            w.Sheets("Pe t-1").Cells(t, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, lColumn)
            w.Sheets("F").Cells(t, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, lColumn)
            w.Sheets("F t-1").Cells(t, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, lColumn)
            w.Sheets("A t-1").Cells(t, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, lColumn)
            w.Sheets("S").Cells(t, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, lColumn)

        Else

'add it to the end of IS3Array



                    ReDim Preserve IS3(LBound(IS3) To UBound(IS3) + 1)
                    IS3(UBound(IS3)) = WBArray(lRow, 1)

                    k = UBound(IS3)



            w.Sheets("C").Cells(k + 1, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, lColumn)
            w.Sheets("M").Cells(k + 1, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, lColumn)
            w.Sheets("W t-1").Cells(k + 1, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, lColumn)
            w.Sheets("P").Cells(k + 1, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, lColumn)
            w.Sheets("A").Cells(k + 1, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, lColumn)
            w.Sheets("PC").Cells(k + 1, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, lColumn)
            w.Sheets("AM").Cells(k + 1, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, lColumn)
            w.Sheets("AM t-1").Cells(k + 1, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, lColumn)
            w.Sheets("P t-1").Cells(k + 1, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, 17)
            w.Sheets("F").Cells(k + 1, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, lColumn)
            w.Sheets("F t-1").Cells(k + 1, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, lColumn)
            w.Sheets("A t-1").Cells(k + 1, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, 18)
            w.Sheets("S").Cells(k + 1, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, lColumn)

        End If
       Next lColumn
  Next lRow







'copy the file date from each source workbook to output workbook
'if the control sheet name (FILES) is changed, please change it in this loop
        For Each ws In w.Worksheets
            If ws.Name <> "FILES" Then
                ws.Cells(1, i + 3) = w2.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 2)
            End If
        Next ws

'Close file And Save
    w2.Close True

Next i

'paste the is3 array to all worksheets
    g = UBound(IS3)

For Each ws In w.Worksheets

    If ws.Name <> "FILES" Then
     ws.Range("A1:A" & g).Value =   Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(IS3)
    End If

Next ws

'Optimize Macro Speed
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic



End Function

Public Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, Arr As Variant) As Long
Dim position As Long
'default return value if value not found in array
IsInArray = -1
If IsArrayEmpty(Arr) Then Exit Function

For position = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr) 'subscript out of range
    If Arr(position) = stringToBeFound Then
        IsInArray = position + 1
        Exit For
    End If
Next

End Function

Public Function IsArrayEmpty(Arr As Variant) As Boolean
Dim LB As Long
Dim UB As Long

Err.Clear
On Error Resume Next
If IsArray(Arr) = False Then
    IsArrayEmpty = True
End If

' Attempt to get the UBound of the array. If the array is unallocated, an error will occur.
UB = UBound(Arr, 1)
If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
    IsArrayEmpty = True
Else

Err.Clear
LB = LBound(Arr)
    If LB > UB Then
        IsArrayEmpty = True
    Else
        IsArrayEmpty = False
    End If
End If

End Function
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Apparently the best way to approach this problem was to state the variables before the pasting loop. This way it runs without iterating excessively. I pasted this new part of the code as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found that the best way to do this, without having to loop through all the columns for each row in each file, and without having to create any Header array, is to state the variables I want before, assign each to a column with the IsInArray function. After that I assign the result of the IsInArray function to a variable and use it to paste to my output file. 
The parts of the code that have been changed:

```
C = IsInArray2("C", WBArray)
M = IsInArray2("M", WBArray)
W0 = IsInArray2("W t-1", WBArray)
P = IsInArray2("P", WBArray)
Ac= IsInArray2("Ac, WBArray)
PC = IsInArray2("PC", WBArray)
AM = IsInArray2("AM", WBArray)
AM = IsInArray2("AM t-1", WBArray)
P = IsInArray2("Pt-1", WBArray)
F = IsInArray2("F", WBArray)
F0 = IsInArray2("F t-1", WBArray)
A0 = IsInArray2("Act-1", WBArray)
S = IsInArray2("S", WBArray)




'loop to match information in two arrays

        For lRow = 2 To UBound(WBArray)
                If IsInArray((WBArray(lRow, 1)), IS3) <> -1 Then
                    t = IsInArray((WBArray(lRow, 1)), IS3)

                        If C <> -1 Then w.Sheets("C").Cells(t, i + 3) =     WBArray(lRow, C) Else: w.Sheets("C").Cells(t, i + 3) = "--"
                        If M <> -1 Then w.Sheets("M").Cells(t, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, M) Else: w.Sheets("M").Cells(t, i + 3) = "--"
                        If W0 <> -1 Then w.Sheets("W t-1").Cells(t, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, W0) Else: w.Sheets("W t-1").Cells(t, i + 3) = "--"
                        If P <> -1 Then w.Sheets("P").Cells(t, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, P) Else: w.Sheets("P").Cells(t, i + 3) = "--"
                        If A <> -1 Then w.Sheets("A").Cells(t, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, A) Else: w.Sheets("A").Cells(t, i + 3) = "--"
                        If PC <> -1 Then w.Sheets("PC").Cells(t, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, PC) Else: w.Sheets("PC").Cells(t, i + 3) = "--"
                        If AM <> -1 Then w.Sheets("AM").Cells(t, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, AM) Else: w.Sheets("AM").Cells(t, i + 3) = "--"
                        If AM0 <> -1 Then w.Sheets("AM t-1").Cells(t, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, AM0) Else: w.Sheets("AM t-1").Cells(t, i + 3) = "--"
                        If P0 <> -1 Then w.Sheets("P t-1").Cells(t, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, P0) Else: w.Sheets("P t-1").Cells(t, i + 3) = "--"
                        If F <> -1 Then w.Sheets("F").Cells(t, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, F) Else: w.Sheets("F").Cells(t, i + 3) = "--"
                        If F0 <> -1 Then w.Sheets("F t-1").Cells(t, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, F0) Else: w.Sheets("F t-1").Cells(t, i + 3) = "--"
                        If A0 <> -1 Then w.Sheets("A t-1").Cells(t, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, A0) Else: w.Sheets("A t-1").Cells(t, i + 3) = "--"
                        If S<> -1 Then w.Sheets("S").Cells(t, i + 3) = WBArray(lRow, S) Else: w.Sheets("S").Cells(t, i + 3) = "--"
```

The last thing is that I created a second IsInArray function, where the next step is just position, and not position + 1